# VIM theme coloring Python variables and functions

Tags: linux, python, vim

I am looking for a VIM theme for python that provides coloring for variables and functions.

The current theme only colors strings and special characters. Has anyone encountered a theme that provides more coloring?

[image: current VIM theme]

Answer (score 1):

I like [seoul256](https://github.com/junegunn/seoul256.vim) and [gruvbox](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox), but you can find lots of them [here](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4071).

[BadWolf](https://github.com/sjl/badwolf) is quite popular, but silimar to the one you showed.